# Key binding to reload .emacs after changing it?

Tags: emacs, dot-emacs

As a novice Emacs user (I'm about 3 months into what's probably a lifelong journey), I make changes to my `.emacs` file pretty regularly.  It would be handy to have a global key binding to reload `.emacs` rather than go through the incredibly laborious process of `M-x load-file` (delete a long string if I'm deep into some directory) `~/.emacs <RET>`.  I've attempted a solution, but

```
;; reload .emacs when C-c <f12> is pressed                                      
(defun reload-dotemacs ()
  (load-file "~/.emacs"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c <f12>")
                (lambda() (interactive) 'reload-dotemacs))
```

doesn't seem to work.  Basically, when I enter the key combination, nothing happens, whereas trying `M-x load-file ~/.emacs` makes things happen (e.g. I see my `yasnippet` files reload).

For the record, `C-c <f12>` doesn't seem to be bound to anything else.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Fix for your code

```
(defun reload-dotemacs ()
  (interactive)
  (load-file "~/.emacs"))
(global-set-key (kbd "C-c <f12>") 'reload-dotemacs)
```

### You do not need it 1

You do not need to remove the default string when you do <kbd>M-x load-file RET</kbd> - just type <kbd>~/.emacs.el RET</kbd> and it will work.

### You do not need it 2

Do not reload the init file, just evaluate the new code.

Type <kbd>C-h m</kbd> and <kbd>C-h b</kbd> in the `.emacs.el` buffer and you will see the useful keybindings (after searching for `eval`):

```
C-c C-b         eval-current-buffer
C-c C-r         eval-region
C-M-x           eval-defun
C-j             eval-print-last-sexp
C-x C-e         eval-last-sexp
```

Comment: I keep multiple instances of Emacs open, so it's nice to be able to have a simple key binding to reload `.emacs`.  For example, I use MobileOrg, so now I can add a line to org-mobile-files if I create a new `.org` file I want on my phone, and then edit and push that file in my other Emacs instance.